# Is amorphous ice thermodynamically stable?

Tags: phase-transition, stability, ice, glass, amorphous-solids

[Amorphous ice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_ice) is often produced by cooling liquid water below its glass transition temperature so fast that it does not have time to form ice crystals. The fact that this can only occur if the temperature change is fast suggests to me that amorphous ice is unstable and results in the system getting "stuck" at a local but not global minimum of the thermodynamic free energy, which would imply that a sharp local perturbation could trigger ice nucleation within an amorphous solid.

Is this correct? Are there certain regions of the temperature-pressure phase diagram for water where the crystalline ice phase is the global minimal of the free energy as a function of some crystalline ice order parameter, and other regions where the amorphous ice phase is the global minimum? Or is the crystalline ice phase always the global minimum?

Are there regions of the phase diagram where the amorphous ice and the crystalline ice phases are both local minima, but they have roughly equal free energy, so both phases are metastable? If so, can there be a first-order phase transition directly between the crystalline and the amorphous ice phases? If so, does such a phase transition have a name?

(My question also applies for other amorphous solids, but I suspect that the answer is very complicated in general, so I'll stick to water for concreteness.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

([Cunningham’s law](https://meta.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/Cunningham%27s_Law) will furnish you with any more accurate answer, but for now, your understanding seems totally reasonable.)

The thermodynamically most stable phase (of [water](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/08/Phase_diagram_of_water.svg), at least) is always crystalline. Any amorphous phase is kinetically limited from crystallizing, although this would yield a Gibbs free energy benefit.

Comment: So just so I understand: the "ice" part of the phase diagram for water can be divided into three regions (not phases!)?
1. A region where the crystalline phase is the only local minimum of the free energy, so you can't get either amorphous ice or supercooled liquid (even metastably).
2. A region where the liquid phase is a local minimum but the crystalline ice phase is the global minimum, so you can supercool liquid water into a metastable liquid state....

Comment: 3. A region where the amorphous solid phase is a local minimum but the crystalline solid is the global minimum, so you can supercool the liquid all the way down to a metastable amorphous solid.
And the glass transition temperature is at the boundary between regions 2 and 3.
Is that correct?

Comment: That's kind of crazy to me that the glass transition is a phase transition from one metastable state to another one, that still doesn't land in the global minimum stable state!

Comment: @tparker - many actual reactions work that way, from nuclear reactions to alloy interactions. Also note that not all amorphous phases are supercooled liquids - amorphous silicon is one example.